# Failed in creating Peer channel in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I am following a tutorial to deploy a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric in multiple organizations available at: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

I followed the pre-requisites and when following the first step, after generated with success the certs and genesis block for the channel, when executing the command:

```
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

It gives the following error:

```
Channel name : mychannel
Creating channel...
2018-08-29 21:10:17.473 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

+ res=1
+ set +x
ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

Anybody know how to fix this ?

Comment: What operating system are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `GOPATH` is set properly.

See if the `crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`
path exist or not. This path is inside the `crypto-config` folder.

Sometimes admin certificates are not accessible due to root user.

Comment: Inside the crypto-config folder I have the path `peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com` but now when I execute the same command it gives another error: http://prntscr.com/kp2kp2